# Eclipse: Shortcut to run Garbage Collector

Tags: eclipse, garbage-collection

The only way to run the garbage collector which I see at the moment is to click the trash button at the bottom on the Eclipse window. This button runs the garbage collection for Eclipse itself.
[Eclipse Trash Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAOxh.jpg)

Is there a way to configure a shortcut in eclipse to run the garbage collector?

Comment: What language is this for? And why would you ever want to manually trigger a garbage collector? It defeats the whole purpose of having a garbage collector.

Comment: Note that this button only runs garbage collection for Eclipse itself - not your programs.

Comment: In my case Eclipse holds a handle on a file I want to delete. When I run the Garbage Collection Eclipse releases the file handle and I can delete the file

Comment: that's a windows problem. on posix systems you can delete open files.

Comment: In case some is looking for this button and it's not visible at the bottom right in your eclipse installation, use Windows -> Preferences -> General -> and activate the Show Heap status checkbox. This is in Eclipse 4.7 (oxygent) but should be valid for previous versions as well

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a shortcut in eclipse by

> Window -> Preferences

In the preferences box go to

> General -> Keys

Then in the Filter search for Garbage. It will show only one option.

select it and in the "Binding" Text Box below Add the Desired shortcut keys for the Garbage Collector.

Then Click "Apply".

And its Done

Comment: I think you refer to the key for the GIT - garbage collection (Catgeory: GIT). I am looking for the garbage collection of Eclips itself.